# How do I get OpenVPN to replace the default route when it connects to avoid an IP leak?

Tags: windows-7, routing, openvpn

Before connecting with OpenVPN's GUI my default route is:

```
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         10.1.1.1         10.1.1.7     10
...
```

After connecting I have:

```
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         10.1.1.1         10.1.1.7     10
          0.0.0.0        128.0.0.0        10.6.0.82        10.6.0.12     20
...
    92.201.74.154  255.255.255.255         10.1.1.1         10.1.1.7     10
...
```

- A new default route is created for all traffic to use VPN (why the 128 in the netmask??)
- Except for traffic directly to the VPN server which uses the real adapter

This is set up by a `redirect-gateway def1`: (from the log) `PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REPLY,...,redirect-gateway def1'`.

The previous default route still exists. Despite the lower metric of the old default route, this setup seems to work. The problem is until I remove the old default route, I'm still quite vulnerable to the WebRTC/STUN IP leak.

Is there any way to get OpenVPN to remove the old default route when it connects so apps can't figure out my real public IP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be simplier ways, but I'm quite a fan of the absolutely sure method. If you create a script that runs prior to initiating your VPN, that deletes your default route, and replaces it with a single route to your VPN address. That way it wouldn't matter what else your comp tried to talk to, it wouldn't have a path to send it through.

Comment: Also, have a script to re-instate your normal default gateway when the VPN goes down.

Comment: @dotvotdot yeah that's quite useful too ;) though you soon notice when its not there...

Comment: thanks. I was just hoping there might be a way to do it with openvpn as it's a pretty common operation. after all it can add routes.